# rotate images 360 degrees

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, css-transitions

I have code:

```
<div class="logo">
<a href="/">
<img src="/images/logo3.png" style="width:180px; margin-top:4px;">
</a>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#topnav #navcontainer .logo:hover {
  transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(-360deg));
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  transition: 2.7s;
}
```

I need to add one more image like:

```
<div class="logo">
<a href="/">
<img src="/images/logo3.png" style="width:180px; margin-top:4px;">
<img src="/images/logo4.png" style="width:180px; margin-top:4px;">
</a>
</div>
```

So the second image will be hide on website, but on hover I need rotate first image and after rotate second image, one by one. First image finish rotation, and than start rotate second image.
How can I realize this animation? May be I need use jQuery also, if someone have idea I will be pleasure.
You can see for example how working now rotation with one image on website.
[example](http://www.crushmash.ru/) if you hover logo in left top side. Now it's working with one image. And I need add second image and rotate one by one.

Comment: so the second image will appear as soon as the first image has completed the rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in pure css you can use an `animation` to obtain a rotation of the first image and a `transition` to show the second image after the first rotation has completed and using the same rotation effect with a 2-seconds delay:

e.g. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvGNvO?editors=110

---

Relevant CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% { transform: rotateY(0)  }
    100% { transform: rotateY(-360deg) }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    0% { transform: rotateY(0)  }
    100% { transform: rotateY(-360deg) }
}
@keyframes rotate {
    0% { transform: rotateY(0)  }
    100% { transform: rotateY(-360deg) }
}


img + img { 
   opacity: 0;

   /* on :hover the opacity turn to 1 (in 0s) with a delay of 2 seconds */
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0s 2s;
   -moz-transition: opacity 0s 2s;
   transition: opacity 0s 2s;
}

a:hover img {

    /* the animation is applied to both the images but... */
    -webkit-animation: rotate 2s linear 0s;
    -moz-animation: rotate 2s linear 0s;
    animation: rotate 2s linear 0s;
}

a:hover img + img {
    opacity: 1;

    /* ... for this image the rotation effect starts 2 seconds later */
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

Comment: Looks similar, but what if I need rotate second image instead of first image. Hide first image after it's finish transition, and load second image rotation.

Comment: the rationale behind this approach is the same. just apply the transition and animation to the image you want